# How to show collapsible content correctly inside an array map?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I made an array of object and map the array. I also make a simple collapsible.
The thing is, the collapsible didn't work correctly. It should only show the content where the user clicked on. *i.e.* when the user click the button belongs to John Doe, the collapsible should show the status belongs to him. What happen to my code is, it shows everyone's status. I have tried with key={index} but still no result.

Here's my code so far...

```
import { useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [showCollapsible, setShowCollapsible] = useState(false);

  const myDatas = [
    {
      id: 1,
      fullName: "John Doe",
      age: 28,
      status: "On Duty",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      fullName: "Jane Doe",
      age: 27,
      status: "Rest",
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      fullName: "James Doe",
      age: 32,
      status: "Take a leave",
    },
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      {myDatas.map((data, index) => {
        return (
          <div>
            <p>{data.fullName}</p>
            <p>{data.age}</p>
            <button
              key={index}
              onClick={() => setShowCollapsible(!showCollapsible)}
            >
              Status
            </button>
            {showCollapsible && <div>{data.status}</div>}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same single boolean state to toggle ***all*** of the collapsible divs. Instead, store some state that uniquely identifies a mapped element, like the data's `id` property. Use the id to check if the div should be collapsed or visible.

```
const App = () => {
  const [showCollapsible, setShowCollapsible] = useState({});

  const myDatas = [
    {
      id: 1,
      fullName: "John Doe",
      age: 28,
      status: "On Duty"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      fullName: "Jane Doe",
      age: 27,
      status: "Rest"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      fullName: "James Doe",
      age: 32,
      status: "Take a leave"
    }
  ];

  const toggleCollapsable = (id) => () => {
    setShowCollapsible((set) => ({
      ...set,
      [id]: !set[id]
    }));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {myDatas.map((data) => {
        return (
          <div>
            <p>{data.fullName}</p>
            <p>{data.age}</p>
            <button onClick={toggleCollapsable(data.id)}>Status</button>
            {showCollapsible[data.id] && <div>{data.status}</div>}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit how-to-show-collapsible-content-correctly-inside-an-array-map]

It would be a little more clean to abstract a `Collapsible` component that manages that state.

```
const CollapsibleDiv = ({ children }) => {
  const [showCollapsible, setShowCollapsible] = useState(false);

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setShowCollapsible((show) => !show)}>
        Status
      </button>
      {showCollapsible && children}
    </>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const myDatas = [
    {
      id: 1,
      fullName: "John Doe",
      age: 28,
      status: "On Duty"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      fullName: "Jane Doe",
      age: 27,
      status: "Rest"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      fullName: "James Doe",
      age: 32,
      status: "Take a leave"
    }
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      {myDatas.map((data) => {
        return (
          <div>
            <p>{data.fullName}</p>
            <p>{data.age}</p>
            <CollapsibleDiv>
              <div>{data.status}</div>
            </CollapsibleDiv>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit how-to-show-collapsible-content-correctly-inside-an-array-map (forked)]

Comment: Wow, I never thought it'll that complex. Also, the clean code one seems simple and yet it work. Thanks dude! I'll try to understand the code.